# Insert value like user-defined datatype by cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

A have own Oracle datatype

```
CREATE TYPE lids_geomtype AS OBJECT(
 type  NUMBER (6),
 source_type  NUMBER (4)
);
```

I can read this datatype by cx_Oracle. This is expample:

```
sql = 'SELECT geomtype FROM poly_gr where id = 4034'
cur.execute(sql)
data = cur.fetchall()
geom =  data[0][0]
print type(geom)
print geom.TYPE, geom.SOURCE_TYPE
print geom.type

************** Result is *****************
<type 'cx_Oracle.OBJECT'>
1002.0 6.0   
<cx_Oracle.ObjectType TARGET.LIDS_GEOMTYPE>
```

But I have problem with INSERT by cx_Oracle.

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO poly (geomtype) VALUES (:1)'
cur.execute(sql,"TARGET.LIDS_GEOMTYPE(1002,6)")
```

Code which is above is wrong because the data type is not VARCHAR2. Could you tell me how can I create cx_Oracle.ObjectType TARGET.LIDS_GEOMTYPE for insert?

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO poly (geomtype) VALUES (%s)' %"TARGET.LIDS_GEOMTYPE(1002,6)"
cur.execute(sql)
```

Code as stated below is OK. But I will use executemany() in next step and there are variables necessary.

Comment: Have you tried instantiating `cx_Oracle.OBJECT`?

Comment: I don´t know how create `cx_Oracle.OBJECT` from prepare data. It is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table, change data type of *geomtype* into your defined object

```
ALTER TABLE poly MODIFY geomtype lids_geomtype;
```

Comment: This is not a problem. Column geomtype has set lids_geomtype datatype. Problem is interpretation by cx_Oracle module. I don´t  know how change interpretation to `cx_Oracle.ObjectType TARGET.LIDS_GEOMTYPE`